# Wake android phone from sleep

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I am trying to develop an Android app with Adobe AIR which can wake the phone from sleep, I am just developing for a single phone for an installation so I have more controls over the settings. A little more background info:

- The phone will always be running my app (locked in kiosk mode)
- By default, the screen will be off
- I will push a message to the app via sockets
- The screen needs to turn on

So far, I have googled around and only managed to find discussions on keeping the screen on but nothing on turning on the screen. Does anyone know any code / native extensions that can achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: That sounds like something the OS/user wants to control

Comment: You cannot control when screen goes on/off. This is valid for both iOS and Android ( native also ).  What could you do is to have the app always started and just display black screen when in idle mode.... this way you do not need to start/stop screen.

Comment: That can only be done outside the app.  Like push notifications come from os.  Push notifications is probably as close as you can get - turns phone on, tap notification in status to activate app.  You can only keep your app running (wake_lock) all the time.  It can't activate itself or force itself to front.